# How to edit this php function and add fake online users as additional?

Tags: php, sql-server

How can I add "fake additional online users". Lets say I have real 30 but I need additional 30 fake. Any ideas how to tweak this up ?

```
  function GetLoggedInCount()
  {
   $cachefile = './cache/playercount.txt';
   $db = $this->database[ADB];   
   if (!file_exists($cachefile) || (time() - 300) >= filemtime($cachefile))
   {
    $count = 0;
    $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT COUNT(strCharID) as pCount FROM CURRENTUSER');
    if ($num_rows == 1)
    {
     $row = $db->doRead();
     $count = $row['pCount'];
     $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
     fwrite($fp, $count);
     fclose($fp);
    }
    return $count;
   }
   else if ((time() - 300) < filemtime($cachefile))
   {
    $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($cachefile));
    fclose($fp);
    return intval($content);
   }
  }
```

Comment: If you're going to lie about how many users are online on your site, why bother with this c*** and not simply do `$onlineUsers = mt_rand(1000,4000);`

Comment: If you have 30 real users, and want 30 fake.. why not `$online_users = $real_users*2` ?

Comment: Just add +30 to the $count? ( :] )

Comment: Can I add +30 on the select query ? Since 30 to count doesnt seems to work. It still checks real users.